# Magento 2 Payment not being captured

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, token, worldpay

I have a problem with OnePageCheckout. Using **Magento ver 2.1.8**, **AheadWorks OnePageCheckout** extension and **World Pay** as a payment gateway.

I get this error:

```
Payment failed, please try again later One of Token or Payment page config must be provided
```

Anyone can help? anyone can direct?